# Find $P(X=Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with same geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with the same geometric distribution with parameter $p$, find:

$P(X = Y)$ and $P(X \geq Y)$

I have done the joint distribution table of both variables and found, with some sums, these results, but I don't find in books some confirmation of my procedures:

1) $\frac{p}{2-p}$

2) $\frac{1}{2-p}$

Comment: Which parameterization of the geomtric distribution are you using? Supported on $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ or on $\{1,2,\dots\}$?

Comment: It's {0,1,2,...}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For the first: you have
  $$
  \mathbb{P}\{X=Y\} = \mathbb{P}\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \{X=Y=k\} =  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}\{X=Y=k\} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}\{X=k\} \cdot \mathbb{P}\{Y=k\} 
  $$
  the second equality since the events are disjoint; the last equality by independence of $X,Y$. Using the pmf of the Geometric distribution, we get
  $$
  \mathbb{P}\{X=Y\} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty p(1-p)^{k-1}\cdot p(1-p)^{k-1} = p^2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p)^{2k} = \frac{p^2}{1-(1-p)^2} = \boxed{\frac{p}{2-p}}
  $$
  where to compute the sum we used the expression of a geometric series.
- For the second, we can do something a bit more "fun": note that
  $$
  \mathbb{P}\{X\geq Y\} = \mathbb{P}\{X = Y\} + \mathbb{P}\{X > Y\} \tag{1}
  $$
  and that $\mathbb{P}\{X > Y\} = \mathbb{P}\{X < Y\}$ by symmetry *(Why?)*. Since 
  $$
  1 = \mathbb{P}\{X = Y\} + \mathbb{P}\{X > Y\} + \mathbb{P}\{X < Y\} \tag{2}
  $$
  *(Why?)* we thus get
  $$
  \mathbb{P}\{X > Y\} = \frac{1-\mathbb{P}\{X = Y\}}{2}
  $$ 
  and therefore by (1)
  $$
  \mathbb{P}\{X\geq Y\} =  \mathbb{P}\{X = Y\}+\frac{1-\mathbb{P}\{X = Y\}}{2} = \frac{1+\mathbb{P}\{X = Y\}}{2}
  $$
  which you can compute given the first part:
  $$
  \frac{1+\frac{p}{2-p}}{2} = \boxed{\frac{1}{2-p}}\,.
  $$

Comment: I had done the second by a double sum and I didn't trust in it, but your method it's beautiful !

Comment: @EduardoGM Symmetry is a beautiful thing :)

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks for neat solution

Answer (score 1):

Write $q=1-p$

a)

$$P(X=Y) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty}P((X=n)\cap (Y=n)) $$
$$ =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}P(X=n)P(Y=n) $$
$$ =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}q^{n-1}p q^{n-1}p  =p^2\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}q^{2n} $$

$$ = p^2{1\over 1-q^2}= {p\over 1+q} = {p\over 2-p}$$

---

b)

$$P(X\geq Y) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\sum _{k=1}^nP((X=n)\cap (Y=k)) $$
$$ =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}P(X=n)\sum _{k=1}^nP(Y=k) $$
$$ =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}q^{n-1}p \sum _{k=1}^nq^{k-1}p  =p^2\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}q^{n-1}\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}q^{k} $$

$$  =p^2\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}q^{n}{1-q^{n}\over 1-q} $$
$$  =p\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}q^{n}(1-q^{n}) $$
$$  =p\Big(\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}q^{n}-\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}q^{2n}\Big) $$
$$ = p({1\over 1-q}-{1\over 1-q^2}) = 1 - {1\over 1+q} = {q\over 1+q}$$

Comment: There is a mistake in the second part: when computing the inner sum, you are getting an extra factor q that shouldn't be there (given the partial sum of a geometric series indexed from 0).